# Appending columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4000x8 excel spreadsheet data which read through dataframe, later I performed slice operation to reduced data size to 1000x8 and computed mean of it.

I am planning to read "n" number of files and want to append computed mean to once specific spreadsheet which holds data of computed mean from all independent spreadsheet.

I am stuck in last part as I am iterating through for loop for "n" different spreadsheets, computed mean dataframe is being overwritten.

Please suggest possible options to solve this problem.

Note: I have just started working with PYTHON and PANDAS.

```
import pandas as pd

directory = 'xyz'

dp=1000

n=2

for i in range(0,n):
    
    path = directory+str(i)+'.xlsx'
    
    data = pd.read_excel(path, header = 4, sheet_name = 0)
    
    lr = data.last_valid_index()

    mdata = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data, index=range(lr,lr-dp,-1)).mean()).iloc[1:,:]
    mdata.columns=["x"+str(i)]
```

Comment: Hey Ankit,
       When you append the data, you are appending as a column correct ? If this is the case, you will want to expand your last statement. 
```python
mdata.columns = mdata.columns.append(['x' + str(i)])
```

Comment: Hi @UGuntupalli, 
I am using `mdata.columns=['x'+str(i)]` to update column name.  Object mdata is holding computed mean of 1000x8 spreadsheet data in one column at particular iteration. Now I want to append next iteration mean to same dataframe as a new column.
How can I achieve this?
Please pardon me if this is trivial and I am interpreting it otherwise, I am pretty new to this.

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example so I can address your question ?